# Dataframe group certain rows

Tags: dataframe

I am wondering if there is a way or I just need to loop through my dataframe to group rows where my index is greater than, in other words based in the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"Name": ["Apple", "Carrot", "Pear", "Tomato", "Orage", "Pineapple", "Mandarin"],"Value": [10,5,6,3,8,9,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

I will get something like

```
        Name  Value
0      Apple     10
1     Carrot      5
2       Pear      6
3     Tomato      3
4      Orage      8
5  Pineapple      9
6   Mandarin      9
```

If I sum all the values I should get 50, is there a way that I can create a "summary" of this dataframe, for instance display the first 3 and group the rest so my results looks like:

```
        Name  Value
0      Apple     10
1     Carrot      5
2       Pear      6
3      Other     29
```

Where 29 is 50 minus (10+5+6) and other was just a random name i gave it?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a programming than a data science question and would therefore be better suited for the stackoverflow page. There are two ways of doing this, depending on the number of items/rows you want to leave separate and if you can manually provide them. Both methods first change the `Name` column to group names in your example and then group and sum the rows.

```
import numpy as np

# manually provide three items which should not be grouped
(
    df
    .assign(Name = lambda x: np.where(~x["Name"].isin(["Apple", "Carrot", "Pear"]), "Other", x["Name"]))
    .groupby("Name")
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)

# automatically use items after third row for grouping
(
    df
    .assign(Name = lambda x: np.where(x["Name"].isin(x["Name"].iloc[3:]), "Other", x["Name"]))
    .groupby("Name")
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)
```